# my first c++ program runtime is super long like 5 - 10 minutes on a fast CPU it's a very basic c++ program

Tags: c++, loops, optimization

i just dont understand whats taking so long
its the standard hello world program you write when you first start to learn a new language and its just so un-optimized

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
  std::string hello_world = "HELLO WORLD!";
  std::string letters =  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ !";
  std::vector<long> positions;
  std::ostringstream oss;
  for(auto l : hello_world){
      int position = 0;
      position = letters.find(l);
      positions.push_back(position);
  }
  for(long t = 0; t <= 100000000000; t++){
    if(t%256465445 == 0){
           for(auto p : positions){
              oss<<letters[p];
           }
    }
  }
  std::cout<<"Hello World!";
}
```

Comment: _"its the standard hello world program ..."_ Nope! Hello World for C++ is `#include <iostream> int main() { std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl; }`

Comment: These standard examples are really something nowadays.

Comment: Apparently the mythical "sufficiently smart compiler" is still mythical, the useless nonsense is not removed.

Comment: You don't understand what's taking so long, and the rather big number 100000000000 does not give you any hint at all?

Comment: The smell of trolling is strong here : *its the standard hello world program you write when you first start to learn a new language and its just so un-optimized* ... with a for-loop of 100000000000 iterations...yeah "*learning a new language*"

Answer (score 2):

This seems like it was purposefully un-optimized.  I would assume that the time constraints are coming from modding a variable 100,000,000,000 times.  But wait, that is not all.  Not only do you mod a variable that many times, but when a variable modded to 0, you iterate another 11 times over each char in "Hello World!", or, more precisely, 389 times.  That means that the last for loop needs to have done at least 100,000,004,279 calculations.  How about you just remove that last for loop, because it seems useless other than to kill time, you'd be better off just doing a sleep(5).